# Get Specific attribute value from python library sholarly.py output

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to python and Django. I am trying the python library "[scholarly.py](https://github.com/scholarly-python-package/scholarly)" to gather article url (to pdf or to eprint) on a django webpage.

Here's what the sample input looks like:

```
>>> search_query = scholarly.search_pubs('Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3D objects')
>>> print(next(search_query))
```

Here's what the output looks like:

```
{'bib': {'abstract': 'Humans can judge from vision alone whether an object is '
                 'physically stable or not. Such judgments allow observers '
                 'to predict the physical behavior of objects, and hence '
                 'to guide their motor actions. We investigated the visual '
                 'estimation of physical stability of 3-D objects (shown '
                 'in stereoscopically viewed rendered scenes) and how it '
                 'relates to visual estimates of their center of mass '
                 '(COM). In Experiment 1, observers viewed an object near '
                 'the edge of a table and adjusted its tilt to the '
                 'perceived critical angle, ie, the tilt angle at which '
                 'the object',
     'author': ['SA Cholewiak', 'RW Fleming', 'M Singh'],
     'cites': '23',
     'eprint': 'https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleID=2213254',
     'gsrank': '1',
     'title': 'Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3-D '
              'objects',
     'url': 'https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleID=2213254',
     'venue': 'Journal of vision',
     'year': '2015'},
 'citations_link': '/scholar?cites=15736880631888070187&as_sdt=5,33&sciodt=0,33&hl=en',
 'filled': False,
 'source': 'scholar',
 'url_add_sclib': '/citations?hl=en&xsrf=&continue=/scholar%3Fq%3DPerception%2Bof%2Bphysical%2Bstability%2Band%2Bcenter%2Bof%2Bmass%2Bof%2B3D%2Bobjects%26hl%3Den%26as_sdt%3D0,33&citilm=1&json=&update_op=library_add&info=K8ZpoI6hZNoJ&ei=ewEtX7_JOIvrmQHcvJqoDA',
 'url_scholarbib': '/scholar?q=info:K8ZpoI6hZNoJ:scholar.google.com/&output=cite&scirp=0&hl=en'}
```

As you can see this output looks like JSON but it is not JSON.
What do I have to do if I want to get only "url" value from that output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you get returned from the iterator is most likely a Python dictionary and you can access it as such:

```
>>> next(search_query).bib['url']
'https://jov.arvojournals.org/article.aspx?articleID=2213254'
```

Looking a little bit at the limited [documentation](https://scholarly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#example) of that script you might have to play with the `.fill` function aswell.

Comment: Thanks Robin.

    >>> next(search_query)['bib']['url']

This didnt actually work but this lead me to right answer. which is:

    >>> next(search_query).bib['url']

Thanks again :)